# concatenating string in bash

Tags: bash, unix, concatenation

I'm having trouble concatenating this string together. My goal is to have `/folder/p/t/e`

test.txt contains the string "test".

```
cat test.txt|cd /folder/p/`awk '{print substr($,0,1)}'`/`awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'`
```

it is outputting `/folder/p/t/` so I think there is something wrong with the second substr part of it.

Could anyone help shed light on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: must it be done in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `awk` instance is capturing all of stdin, so your second isn't reading anything in it. Whatever reads stdin must be a single command.

```
cat test.txt | cd /folder/p/`awk '{print substr($0,0,1)"/"substr($0,2,1)}'`
```

Comment: Avoid useless `cat` ! Use: `awk < text.txt ...` instead of `cat text.txt | awk ...` !!

Comment: could (better) be written: `cd $(awk < test.txt '{printf "/folder/p/%s", substr($0,0,1)"/"substr($0,2,1)}')`

Comment: @F.Hauri actually, it could be better written with a mild adaptation of @Beta's parameter expansion. `x=$(<test.txt); cd "/folder/p/${x:0:1}/${x:1:1}"` But that's not what I was going for. I was trying to explain why OP's solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOO=$(< test.txt)
cd /folder/p/${FOO:0:1}/${FOO:1:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that your second call to `awk` will get something from `test.txt`, which it doesn't. 
The text from `cat test.txt` is piped to the command after the pipe and the command in the sub-shell (the first `awk`) receives all the input, leaving no input for the second `awk`, as kojiro already answered.

While merging both `awk` commands will fix the problem, is is not guaranteed that this will work in other
shells. Because many people confuse `bash` with 'shell' in general I think it's noteworthy that a more portable solution would be the one made by Beta.

Comment: I know that it hasn't anything to do with `cd` being no builtin. I was mentioning it just to educate.